# How to send an email to a UNIQUE group of recipients with contents based on CSV

Tags: email, powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm not exactly sure how to phrase this question so that it makes sense.
I have a CSV that contains User, Manager and Manager Email Address. The Manager and Manager email address columns will contain duplicates, but are sorted. See the below image.

[image]

I want to send an email to the manager with the contents and recipient being dynamically based upon the CSV.

```
$Outlook = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application 
         $Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0) 
         $Mail.Recipients.Add("sally@x.com")
         $Mail.Subject = "People" 
         $Mail.Body = "Bob, John, Joe"
         $Mail.Send()
```

That's not a problem, I understand that. What I need to know how to do is make it so that only one email is sent per manager.

For example, Email 1 would be sent to Sally@x.com and the contents would be Bob, John, Joe. Email 2 would be sent to Brian@x.com with the contents Joe. Email 3 would be sent to Joey@x.com with the contents Ally, Alex.

What I can't have is one email sent to the manager per user. In other words, Sally receiving 3 emails, Joey receiving 2.

I can't even figure out where to start with this. I feel like because it's sorted, I should be able to do a foreach unique managermail in the list...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should help.

```
$uniqMailList = Import-Csv .\your.csv | Select -expand ManagerMail -Unique 

foreach ($mailItem in $uniqMailList)
{
    $names = Import-Csv .\your.csv | Where-Object {$_.ManagerMail -eq "$mailItem"} | Select -expand User;

     $Outlook = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application 
       $Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0) 
       $Mail.Recipients.Add($mailItem)
       $Mail.Subject = "People" 
       $Mail.Body = $names
       $Mail.Send()

}
```

Comment: I definitely think this will work with the -expandproperty, but I'm running into an issue where it's not recognizing the multiple managermail's as separate. When I add in a breakpoint, it shows "sally@x.com Brian@x.com Joey@x.com" I thought Import-csv automatically piped into an array...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    $Outlook = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application
    $liste=import-csv -Path C:\temp\myliste.csv -Delimiter ";" | group ManagerMail | select name, @{N="Users";E={$_.group.User -join ", "}}
    foreach ($item in $liste)
    {
           $Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0) 
           $Mail.Recipients.Add($item.Name)
           $Mail.Subject = "People" 
           $Mail.Body = $item.Users
           $Mail.Send()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I finally got to work:

```
$file = Import-Csv C:\TEST.CSV |
select -Expand managermail -Unique 

foreach ($item in $file)
{
    $names = Import-Csv C:\TEST.CSV | Where-Object {$_.ManagerMail -eq "$item"} | Select -expand user

    $Outlook = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application 
    $Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0) 
    $Mail.Recipients.Add($item)
    $Mail.Subject = "People" 
    $Mail.Body = "$names"
    $Mail.Send()
}
```